# CSS files give 404 error in production

Tags: magento2, 404, deployment

The problem only occurs on frontend, and it does not occur in admin panel. I am running magento 2.0.4 over Ubuntu with Nginx and php5.6. Any bit runs over https including un-secure based urls.

I already did all of the following:

1. Run `deploy:mode:set production`
2. Delete all `var/*`
3. Deleted `pub/static`
4. Opened up `app/etc/di.xml` and find the virtualType `name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section you'll find an item `name="view_preprocessed"` that needs to be modified or deleted. You can modify it by changing the contents from `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
5. Run `cache:flush` and dumped all cache on admin panel
6. Run `setup:di:compile-multi-tenant`
7. Run `setup:static-content:deploy`
8. Run `indexer:reindex`
9. Run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  .`
10. Run `sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && sudo  find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`

My nginx config file looks like this:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        # use tcp connection
        # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
        # or socket
        server   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.site.com;
       return         301 https://my.site.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my_site_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/my.site.com.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        server_name my.site.com;

        set $MAGE_ROOT /home/ubuntu/www/my.site.com;
        set $MAGE_MODE production;

        include /home/ubuntu/www/my.site.com/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Any other suggestion why I keep getting 404 errors on css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had to do with the default locale. It was set to es_MX and I was compiling to en_US.